# dig +trace returns my DNS IP

Tags: dns

When I'm trying to execute dig +trace command, output is the following:

```
$ dig +trace google.com

; <<>> DiG 9.9.5-3-Ubuntu <<>> +trace google.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Received 12 bytes from 127.0.1.1#53(127.0.1.1) in 10 ms
```

I assume there are some issues with my DNS setup, but I do not know where to look.

Any suggestions?

Comment: There probably are not any issues with your DNS setup, I think Ubuntu comes with a DNS cacher by default to cache DNS lookups.  Not certain about that though.

Answer (score 1):

Took me a bit of digging to find out what is going on here. Basically, the new systemd nonsense has forced itself into the DNS space. If you read /etc/resolv.conf, you'll see it refers to systemd-resolved. You'll also see your nameserver entry is 127.0.0.53.

```
netstat -pntul | grep :53 show: 
tcp 0 0 127.0.0.1:53 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN 29133/named 
tcp 0 0 127.0.0.53:53 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN 27505/systemd-resol
```

But systemd-resolved passes queries NOT to your bind9 server, but to glibc. Unfortunately, glibc isn't a resolver. It will pass queries, but does so in a way that breaks +trace. +notrace works just fine.

To get around this, I removed resolvconf, turned off systemd-resolved, and changed the /etc/resolv.conf entry from 127.0.0.53 to 127.0.0.1.

Before you make the change, you can dig @127.0.0.1 +trace google.com and see that dig +trace works as expected proving the systemd implementation is broken and should be removed.